# Run avconv in python and direct stdout/stderr to a file

Tags: python, ubuntu, avconv

I wish to run Avconv commands and record the logs in a file. In the Ubuntu terminal this can be accomplished using `&>>` operator after the actual command enclosed in parenthesis i.e.

```
(avconv -i SRCFILE -ss 00:15:00 -t 00:30:00 TARGETFILE -threads auto) &>> LOGFILE
```

The above command works perfectly when run in the terminal.

Now I have a number of such commands to run, and thought running them through Python would be good.

1. I tried using the `os.system(command_string)` way
   , which when run does not pack the Avconv output to the LOGFILE, and the avconv command seems to execute after the Python script is done - evidenced by some string outputs I put in for debugging. I'm also getting some permission errors. Here is how the first portion of output looks like

   ```
   AVCONV COMMAND EXECUTED
   sh: 1: : Permission denied
   sh: 1: : Permission denied
   sh: 1: 


   PROGRAM DONE
   : Permission denied
   $ avconv version 11.2-6:11.2-1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
     built on Jan 18 2015 05:12:33 with gcc 4.9.2 (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu2)
   Trailing options were found on the commandline.
   Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from ...
   ```
2. I also tried using the `subprocess.call()` method for which I get the following error (NOTE: all files exist)

   ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/home/usr/cnv.py", line 61, in <module>
       main()
     File "/home/usr/cnv.py", line 46, in main
       subprocess.call(newcmd)
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
       return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
       errread, errwrite)
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
       raise child_exception
   OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
   ```

I wish to run multiple (think 50+) commands of Avconv similar to the version shown at the top, and have the logs saved in a file instead of in stdout. How do I do this - in Python or otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

FILES = ( 
    ( 'FirstSourceFile.avi', 'FirstDestinationFile.mp4' ),
    ( 'SecondSourceFile.avi', 'SecondDestinationFile.mp4' ),
    #  ... and so on...  
)
log_file = open( 'Logfile.txt', 'w' )

for src_name, dst_name in FILES:
    cmd_list = [ 'avconv', '-i', src_name, '-ss', '00:15:00', '-t', '00:30:00', dst_name, '-threads', 'auto' ]
    p1 = Popen( cmd_list, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE )
    p1out, p1err = p1.communicate()
    if p1out is not None: log_file.write( p1out )
    if p1err is not None: log_file.write( p1err )
log_file.close()
```